# Score - Showing the score

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

http://jsfiddle.net/q8P7Y/

I have a problem of showing the final score at the end, there is many ways I can go about doing it but I'm not sure what would be the best.

As you can see the next button is just a show/hide of divs and not pages. The score is an id, so obviously only appearing once and it is outside of the show/hide.

How will I hide the id on the last div and show the score in an ending paragraph?

I thought of changing the score span to a name and then putting the score in every div apart from the last, but then the score wasn't updating even when using

```
document.getElementsByName("score").innerHTML = score;
```

instead of

```
document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = score;
```

But no luck.

Any ideas on how to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you simply update both fields, usign 2 different ids?
I mean, the score summary in the last page coud be something like

```
<table class="widthOneHundredPercent">
  <p>Your score is:<span id="finalScore"></span></p>
</table>
```

And you could update it everytime you update the always visible one, like this

```
$("#score").html(score);
$("#finalScore").html(score);
```

You can find the working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/q8P7Y/3/)

Did it answer your question?

**Edited:**

You could also use a more short way for updating both values:

```
$("#score, #finalScore").html(score);
```

**Edited2:**
For the problem of hiding the upper score part (what you called scoreBoard), for your last "next" button use this code:

```
<input type="button" value="next" onclick="$('#scoreBoard').hide();pagechange(3,4); scrollToTop(); "/>
```

You can find the [working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/q8P7Y/10/)

Answer (score 1):

Just change your HTML to:

```
<p>Your score is: <span id="finalscore"></span></p>
```

and your javascript to:

```
$("#score").html(score);
$("#finalscore").html(score);
```

To hide the score at the top for the final page, change:

```
  <input type="button" value="next" onclick="pagechange(3,4); scrollToTop();"/></center>
```

to:

```
  <input type="button" value="next" onclick="pagechange(3,4); scrollToTop(); hideScoreBoard();"/></center>
```

then add these do your javascript:

```
function hideScoreBoard() {
  $("#scoreBoard").hide();
}

function scrollToTop() {
}
```

Note I have added an empty `scrollToTop()` to stop errors so that the above changes work.

Comment: Thanks, but I still cannot hide the score when on the last viewable div. So now I'll have the score showing twice. How can I hide the score when on the last div?